# Unable to convert Android Studio Recordings to any other video format so that it can be played on Desktop?

Tags: android, video, android-studio

I have recorded Video of the Android App using Android Studio Recording but I am unable to play on Windows Media Player or VLC Media Player?
Though I am to play it on my device.
I tried online video converter tools but none of them help, they do not support the file format?
How can I convert it other video format then??

Comment: It should be a standard MP4 file. I have had no problems playing them on Linux.

Comment: I am using Windows ,it is not playing on Windows Media Player